# Magic numbers in C++ implementation of Excel NORMDIST function

Tags: c++, excel, function, math, magic-numbers

Whilst looking for a C++ implementation of Excel's `NORMDIST` (cumulative)
function I found [this on a website](http://www.alina.ch/oliver/faq-excel-normdist.shtml):

```
static double normdist(double x, double mean, double standard_dev)
{
    double res;
    double x=(x - mean) / standard_dev;
    if (x == 0)
    {
        res=0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        double oor2pi = 1/(sqrt(double(2) * 3.14159265358979323846));
        double t = 1 / (double(1) + 0.2316419 * fabs(x));
        t *= oor2pi * exp(-0.5 * x * x) 
             * (0.31938153   + t 
             * (-0.356563782 + t
             * (1.781477937  + t 
             * (-1.821255978 + t * 1.330274429))));
        if (x >= 0)
        {
            res = double(1) - t;
        }
        else
        {
            res = t;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

My limited maths knowledge made me think about [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), but I am unable to determine where these numbers come from:

`0.2316419`,
`0.31938153`,
`-0.356563782`,
`1.781477937`,
`-1.821255978`, 
`1.330274429`

Can anyone suggest where they come from, and how they can be derived?

Comment: Hm, `3.14159265358979323846` is pretty close to `PI`... ;)

Comment: This question on Math.StackEchange seems to be relevant: [Abramowitz and Stegun approximation for cumulative normal distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888165/abramowitz-and-stegun-approximation-for-cumulative-normal-distribution)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out Numerical Recipes, chapter 6.2.2. The approximation is standard. Recall that

```
NormCdf(x) = 0.5 * (1 + erf(x / sqrt(2)))
erf(x) = 2 / (sqrt(pi)) integral(e^(-t^2) dt, t = 0..x)
```

and write erf as

```
1 - erf x ~= t * exp(-x^2 + P(t))
```

for positive x, where

```
t = 2 / (2 + x)
```

and since t is between 0 and 1, you can find P by [Chebyshev approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) once and for all (Numerical Recipes, section 5.8). You don't use Taylor expansion: you want the approximation to be good in the whole real line, what Taylor expansion cannot guarantee. Chebyshev approximation is the best polynomial approximation in the [L^2 norm](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLp_space&rct=j&q=l%5E2%20norm%20wikipedia&ei=DFdRTd-mHZSq8AOpyKmjCw&usg=AFQjCNHXwaPleXOPfldhOxK6Q1Jl_RTNQw&cad=rja), which is a good substitute to the very difficult to find [minimax polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm) (= best polynomial approximation in the sup norm).

The version here is slightly different. Instead, one writes

```
1 - erf x = t * exp(-x^2) * P(t)
```

but the procedure is similar, and normCdf is computed directly, instead of erf.

**In particular and very similarly 'the implementation' that you are using differs somewhat from the one that handles in the text, because it is of the form `b*exp(-a*z^2)*y(t)` but it´s also a Chevishev approx. to the erfc(x) function as you can see in this paper of Schonfelder(1978)[http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-144/S0025-5718-1978-0494846-8/S0025-5718-1978-0494846-8.pdf ]**

Also in Numerical Recipes 3rd edition, at the final of the chapter 6.2.2 they provide a C implementation very accurate of the type `t*exp(-z^2 + c0 + c1*t+ c2t^2 + c3*t^3 + ... + c9t^9)`